# Maven Remote Resources Plugin is not creating remote-resources.xml manifest file

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module Maven project which uses the same resource files across modules. I created resources project and added resources to src/main/resources folder.
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>project-resources</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

When I do the build, META-INF/maven/remote-resources.xml file is not created.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
   <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
             ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

In other words: also add it to the plugins section not only the pluginManagement section.

Comment: If I do that I get this error message on <execution> tag:
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:bundle (execution: default, phase: generate-resources)

Comment: Where do you get this error? On the command line? In Eclipse? Another IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the execution warning you are encountering - this is a known "issue" in eclipse.  You can handle it through configuration goal delegation:

```
<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
         <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
           <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
             <pluginExecutions>
               <pluginExecution>
                 <pluginExecutionFilter>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                   <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>bundle</goal>
                   </goals>
                 </pluginExecutionFilter>
                 <action>
                   <ignore/>
                 </action>
               </pluginExecution>
             </pluginExecutions>
           </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html